# How to call a function using the package and function name in a string with ::

Tags: r

How can I call a function in a package using the fully qualified name ("package::function")?

This does not work:

```
> eval(call("utils::sessionInfo"))
Error in `utils::sessionInfo`() : 
  could not find function "utils::sessionInfo"
```

This works:

```
eval(call("sessionInfo"))
```

It must be possible to parse and execute a code snippet without internal knowledge, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `call` with `parse`:

```
eval(parse(text = 'utils::sessionInfo()'))
```

For example:

```
eval(parse(text = 'dplyr::count(iris, Species)'))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species        n
  <fctr>     <int>
1 setosa        50
2 versicolor    50
3 virginica     50
```

Comment: works :-) any idea why `call` does not respect namespaces? This is counter-intuitive...